# Error in value[[3L]](cond) : there is no package called ‘plyr’

Tags: r, shinyapps

I am currently trying to launch a shinyapp which works locally on shinyapps.io.

However, whenever I publish the app it comes back with the following message:

> Error in value[3L] : there is no package called ‘plyr’ Calls:
> local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
> Execution halted

This problem is not specific to the package 'plyr', as I have removed this package and have gotten the same error on the next package in my list.

I have installed my packages locally and have called them using the library(package name) command.

I have previously run similar projects with this package library list with no problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Hi Michael, I feel your pain. I'm getting the same problem. I suspect it is due to an issue later in the code than the library() statements. In my case when I removed later code the error disappeared. I'm still trying to track down. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: My issue (slightly different) was fixed by installing the development version of `packrat` from Github see : https://github.com/afrimapr/afrilearnr/issues/4#issue-791404707

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 'markdown' when trying to deploy app.

Looks like locally the app was calling markdown from my cache. I added a library call for 'markdown' within my app.R file and it worked.

'packrat' is the best way to avoid the same issue in the future, thanks Andy